# isHandler Method of RequestMappingHandlerMapping retunrs true for both RequestMapping and Controller annotation

Tags: java, spring

I am looking into Dispatcher Servlet code. Here i found that dispatcher servlet uses HandlerMapping to select the handler for the request. Also, RequestMappingHandlerMapping is used as an implementation for HandlerMapping. Now, isHandlerMethod of RequestMappingHandlerMapping returns true if the bean under consideration has either @Controller or @RequestMapping annotation. If certain bean has only @RequestMapping annotation applied at class level would it still be considered as Handler?.
Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @RequestMapping and @Controller annotation have different meanings. The request mapping is used to decide, which class / method is used to handle a request to a speciffic URL. If you look at the source of the @Controller adnotation you will find that it is annotated with @Component itself. This way it can be used to set up the component scan that will register an instance of the class as a bean.

I'm quessing that, since those annotations are usually used together, it's done so that a minute performance gain can be achieved. Also, you could declare your controllers differently, either by java config or xml.

**Edit:**
I have done a quick prototype with a controller bean declared in java config, without the @Controller annotation. The answer is yes, the method will be used to handle a request, even if the class is not annotated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My doubt is according to isHandler Method of RequestMappingHandlerMapping, even if i annotate my class with just @RequestMapping annotation, it would still be considered as handler class and it's method scanned for handler methods.